# LAB value to image conversion

Tags: python, colors

I have CSV with LAB value, I want to convert that LAB value to image for example from this website https://www.nixsensor.com/free-color-converter/ when I enter LAB value it shows colored image. How can do this with Python? Should I do LAB to RBG if yes how? and then from RGB to image?
TIA
[image]

Comment: In Wikipedia you get the LAB page, there you will find the formulas for conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many Python packages performing this type of conversion, it is two lines with [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) that I maintain:

```py
>>> import colour
>>> colour.XYZ_to_sRGB(colour.Lab_to_XYZ([52, 25, 50])) * 255
array([ 181.13594388,  105.41357976,   34.35930998])
```

Alternatively, with the **Automatic Colour Conversion Graph** and the **CIE Lab** values normalised:

```py
>>> import colour
>>> colour.convert([52. / 100., 25. / 100., 50. / 100.], 'CIE Lab', 'Output-Referred RGB')  * 255
array([ 181.13594388,  105.41357976,   34.35930998])
```

The numerical differences are likely caused by the different illuminants used, *Colour* uses D65 by default.